# Connect Oracle SQL to VBA

Tags: vba, oracle, cx-oracle, oraoledb

I am able to connect Python to my Oracle SQL DB on a Windows computer, but strangely enough I cannot seem to get it working from VBA.

For reference, this is the Python Code to connect:

```
cx_Oracle.connect(f'{self.user}/{self.pwd}@//{self.host}:{self.port}/{self.service_name}')
```

I have tried replicating this similar structure in my VBA code, but I get an error message. Here is the code I've been using:

```
Sub CallDB_Return_Flexible(stSQL As String, rstStart As Range)

    Dim sqlConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rtn As Boolean
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim cs As String

    'On Error Resume Next
    Set sqlConn = New ADODB.Connection

    cs = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;User ID=myuserID;Password=myPsswd;Data Source=host:port/service_name;"
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = cs
    sqlConn.CommandTimeout = 10000
    sqlConn.Open
```

I get the following error messages:
1) The system cannot find message text for message text 0x80040e0c in the message file for OraOLEDB.
2) Sometimes, dependent on the iteration of the connection I use (IE a TNS connection), I get a TNS listener error message.

I currently have the ActiveX 6.1 Data Objects Library enabled. Furthermore, I am on a 64-bit machine with a 64-bit Oracle client installed. I have a 64-bit Office. I am quite certain I have a 64-bit ADO as well - my ODAC (if this is the same) is the same as the 64 bit version online. I have an ODP.NET of 2.12 and another with 4.121 in the registry. I just have an ODP.NET.Managed of 4.12.

This doesn't make much sense to me, how in one language I can connect with no issues, but in another I cannot!

Comment: If you have the 64-bit Oracle client then you need 64-bit Office plus 64-bit ADO.  Do you have those?

Comment: Is the VBA code running from a 64-bit or 32-bit process? Most VBA hosts (like Microsoft Office) are still 32-bit by default - that may be the problem. What happens if you try to use `ADODB.Connection` with `OraOLEDB` from a 64-bit VBScript instead of VBA? (`cscript.exe` is 64-bit).

Comment: I have a 64-bit Office. I am quite certain I have a 64-bit ADO as well - my ODAC (if this is the same) is the same as the 64 bit version online. I have an ODP.NET of 2.12 and another with 4.121. I just have an ODP.NET.Managed of 4.12. Is the 2.12 ODP.NET in the registry throwing off the code?

Comment: When you get a TNS listener error message then your driver installation seems to be OK. Try a different version of ActiveX ?.? Data Objects Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backtested using an earlier ActiveX Data Library - this solved it.

Thank you!!!!!